# Unable to connect Teradata server with authentication mechanism as LDAP

Tags: vba, excel, ldap, teradata

It would be a great help if anyone provides a VBA connection string to connect Excel with Teradata where Authentication mechanism = LDAP.

VBA code used before configuring Authentication mechanism = LDAP is given below. But the code doesn't work when my organisation moved our credentials to support only AUTHENTICATION MECHANISM = LDAP.
Please help!

Code:

```
Public cn As ADODB.Connection
Public rs As ADODB.Connection

Sub test_ter() 
    TDCONSTR1 = "DSN &_ =<dsn_name> ; uid = <usr>; PWD = <PWD>;" 
    Set cn = new ADODB.Connection     
    cn.Open TDCONSTR1
    MsgBox("Connection established")
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Arun! Updated my question as you guided!

Comment: Have you tried to include the connection parameter method=LDAP after PWD? It may be defaulting to TD2.

Comment: Hi All,
I have tried the below connection given by JNevil and it's working fine
"SessionMode=Teradata;Driver=Teradata;Authentication=LDAP;DBCName=<your database IP/Domain name>;Database=<Your default database for connection>;Uid=<username>;Pwd=<pass>"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is what I use to make a connection to Teradata over ODBC using the ADODB library in VBA via LDAP:

```
"SessionMode=Teradata;Driver=Teradata;Authentication=LDAP;DBCName=<your database IP/Domain name>;Database=<Your default database for connection>;Uid=<username>;Pwd=<pass>"
```

Really you just need to specify the Authentication Mechanism via the "Authentication" setting in the connection string `Authentication=LDAP`